# interdependent dropdowns in gridview using declarative programming

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a binded dropdown control in the gridview under edittemplate.
Now i wanted to populate the second dropdown in the same gridview based on the first selection.
I dont have options but use the gridview & declarative coding.

Also i am using the objectdatasource here.

Any help will be of great use.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the question???  Posting completely vague requests is only going to get you completely vague answers.  Like so:

You can do this client-side using javascript (look into jQuery), or server-side by setting the AutoPostBack property of the first dropdown to true.

Comment: Sorry totally forgot to complete the question.
How to make the second dropdown to populate based on the selection of the first dropdown, also if i again go to the edit mode the code breaks for selectedvalue for the second dropdown.